# Differences between Rcpp::is_na, R_IsNA and std::isnan

Tags: c++, rcpp

I want to check if `x` that is a `<double>` does not contain missing value. There are several options:

- `Rcpp::NumericVector::is_na(x)`
- `R_IsNA(x)`
- `std::isnan(x)`

and [others](https://gist.github.com/kevinushey/8911432) like

```
std::memcmp(
    (char*)(&x),
    (char*)(&NA_REAL),
    sizeof(double)
) == 0;
```

What are the differences between those methods? Which one is recommended assuming that `x` is not a vector, so we do not need Rcpp's vectorization?

Comment: I have no idea about `Rcpp`, but `std::isnan` works with C++ floating point-types which may or may not be the same as R types (and may not even be `IEEE-754`-compliant, strictly speaking).

Comment: @Violet: R has both `NA` and `NaN`; and both are defined for several types beyond `double`.  It is very much an extension beyond IEEE 754.

Comment: @Tim: I marked this as duplicate.  The other question has two good answers, and the answer by Kevin pretty thorough.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel  I know the other thread but I'm interested in differences between those functions.

Comment: At the top-level:  The first is for Rcpp vectors, the second is an R primitive (for `SEXP` types) and the third is from the C++ library.   Difference sources, different scopes.

Comment: If you want an extended discussion, I would suggest the rcpp-devel list rather than these comments...